# Deploying c# app by using ClickOnce without signing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, deployment, setup-deployment

I need to deploy my WPF app with ClickOnce. I don't need signing(.pfx certificate) and I am worried if I will ever be prompted to sign it again in the future, as per my knowledge Visual Studio generates a self-signed certificate when I untick this checkbox (see the img). Do these types of self-signed certificates have an expiration date? Can the app auto-update without a problem?

[image]

Comment: Who are your users? If it's an internal app I just go with _self-signed_ (pretty sure you can choose a long expire date too) otherwise if you have external customers you may want to consider purchasing a certificate from a 3rd party so as to be professional

Comment: There is no option for choosing expire date

Comment: If it’s for internal use it doesn’t matter